# In XCTest How to handle Picker wheels when the options in picker wheel are dynamic

Tags: objective-c, xctest

I am trying to automate picker wheel but am not able to pick any of the option in picker wheel

tried with code `[[[[app descendantsMatchingType:XCUIElementTypeAny]  childrenMatchingType:XCUIElementTypePicker] elementMatchingPredicate: [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"2 of 6"]] tap];`

Here is how my accessibility inspector looks [image]

can anyone please help me here

Answer (score 0):

Your current code is comparing the element to "2 of 6", rather than the element's value.

Change your predicate format to `"value CONTAINS '2 of 6'"`.

Comment: It dint work, is there anything I am missing or am going wrong some where

Comment: It's possible that more than one element matched the predicate. Does any of this method help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40843233/how-to-adjust-ios-picker-wheel-to-generated-random-index/40845374#40845374 - obviously ignore the random part :)